Horror movie in a hospital
There was a horror movie happening in a hospital. I remember the horrific possessed/poltergeist was a female, perhaps old woman on wheelchair. And I remember at some point the hospital began to be destroyed like an earthquake is happening and that there were two main characters I guess, a woman and a man (perhaps both doctors at that hospital) and the male actor was one of those actors that played more of villain roles and very few neutral/hero/protagonist roles and probably between 2000 & 2009.
The reason I'm asking is I just saw about 5 to ten minutes of this movie then I had to go to class, and also those moments I saw was from the middle of the movie.

Looking for information what movie it was on the site or TV channel or wherever you saw it might be a first try, though.

@NapoleonWilson it was one of the iranian channels broadcasting from outside of iran , they usually don't have a website!!

Possibly Fragile from 2005 about an evil spirit in a hospital thought to be the ghost of a handicapped girl, but it turns out to be the ghost of an older nurse. The hospital also starts falling apart in the end. It stars Calista Flockhart and Richard Roxburgh, that does usually play villains. Here's the trailer.




possibly , since i don't remember well, and i haven't watched this one , i mark ur answer , hoping this the movie i was looking for , but thanks
